# Jquery each function,count duplicate

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Hello people here is my code below.....

```
var obj = eval(data.inbox_messages);
var nam = '';

$.each(obj,function(index,Object) {
  console.log(Object.From_Name);
  nam += Object.From_Name
});
```

outputs `kothi,kothi` .I need to count number of duplicates inside `Object` and display only one unique `From_Name`, anyways to fix this??

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf):

```
var duplicates = 0;
$.each(obj,function(index,Object) {
  console.log(Object.From_Name);
  if(nam.indexOf(Object.From_Name) == -1) {
    nam += Object.From_Name
  }
  else {
    duplicates += 1;
  }
})
console.log(duplicates);
```

This will look into the string, if there's a already a substring it will skip the concatenation part.

Comment: @EndeNeu but how can i count the number of duplicates??

Comment: @Friend I added the duplicate count to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var unique_values = {};
var list_of_values = [];
$.each(obj,function(index,Object) {
        if ( ! unique_values[Object.From_Name] ) {
            unique_values[Object.From_Name] = true;
            list_of_values.push(Object.From_Name);
        } else {
            // We have duplicate values!
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj = eval(data.inbox_messages);
var nam = '';
var holder = {};

$.each(obj,function(index,Object) {
    if(!holder[Object.From_Name]) {
        holder[Object.From_Name] = 1;
        console.log(Object.From_Name);
        nam += Object.From_Name;
    }
    else {
        holder[Object.From_Name]++;
    }
})
```

Then loop over holder to count the duplicates, skipping those that === 1.